# index.php?ruta=

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, php7

Tengo un aplicativo web bajado de Internet el cual modifique el cual en mi *localhost* funciona todo de maravilla, en cambio al momento de subirlo al hosting empiezan los problemas, me Explico:

en mi localhost la función eliminar categoría si funciona, en cambio en el hosting me aparece un "pestañeo" y me muestra esta ruta:

```
index.php?ruta=categorias&idCategoria=1
```

De lo contrario, en el localhost la opción de editar categoria( que fue remplazado por cliente) no me funciona y al editar me pone los campos en "0" en cambio en el hosting lo hace perfectamente.

## Código

**Como funcion controlador:**

```
static public function ctrBorrarCategoria(){

        if(isset($_GET["idCategoria"])){

            $tabla ="Categorias";
            $datos = $_GET["idCategoria"];

            $respuesta = ModeloCategorias::mdlBorrarCategoria($tabla, $datos);

            if($respuesta == "ok"){

                echo'<script>

                    swal({
                          type: "success",
                          title: "El Cliente a ha sido borrada correctamente",
                          showConfirmButton: true,
                          confirmButtonText: "Cerrar"
                          }).then(function(result){
                                    if (result.value) {

                                    window.location = "categorias";

                                    }
                                })

                    </script>';
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**Como modelo:**

```
static public function mdlEliminarCliente($tabla, $datos){

        $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("DELETE FROM $tabla WHERE id = :id");

        $stmt -> bindParam(":id", $datos, PDO::PARAM_INT);

        if($stmt -> execute()){

            return "ok";

        }else{

            return "error"; 

        }

        $stmt -> close();

        $stmt = null;

    }
```

**Ajax:**

```
$(".tablas").on("click", ".btnEliminarCategoria", function(){

     var idCategoria = $(this).attr("idCategoria");
  //console.log(idCategoria);
     swal({
        title: '¿Está seguro de borrar el Cliente?',
        text: "¡Si no lo está puede cancelar la acción!",
        type: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
        cancelButtonText: 'Cancelar',
        confirmButtonText: 'Si, borrar Cliente!'
     }).then(function(result){

        if(result.value){


            window.location = "index.php?ruta=categorias&idCategoria="+idCategoria;

        }

     })

})
```

**Datos del servidor:**

```
cpsrvd 11.86.0.21
Versión del cliente de base de datos: libmysql - 5.6.43
extensión PHP: mysqliDocumentación curlDocumentación mbstringDocumentación
Versión de PHP: 7.3.6
```

Adjunto fotografia:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
quedo atento, gracias!

IMPORTANTE: El código es categoría, pero fue modificado para Clientes.

**Registro AJax del boton Eliminar categoria**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**HTML de Categoria (utilizado como Cliente)**

```html
<div id="modalAgregarCategoria" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <div class="modal-content">

      <form role="form" method="post">

        <!--=====================================
        CABEZA DEL MODAL
        ======================================-->

        <div class="modal-header" style="background:#3c8dbc; color:white">

          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>

          <h4 class="modal-title">Agregar Cliente</h4>

        </div>

        <!--=====================================
        CUERPO DEL MODAL
        ======================================-->

        <div class="modal-body">

          <div class="box-body">

            <!-- ENTRADA PARA EL NOMBRE -->
            
            <div class="form-group">
              
              <div class="input-group">
              
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span> 

                <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="nuevaCategoria" placeholder="Ingresar Cliente" required>

              </div>
<br>   
              <div class="input-group">
              
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-address-book"></i></span> 

                <input type="number" class="form-control input-lg" name="nuevaRut" placeholder="Ingresar Rut" required>

              </div>
<br>              
                <div class="input-group">
              
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i></span> 

                <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="nuevaDireccion" placeholder="Ingresar Dirección" required>

              </div>
<br>   
              <div class="input-group">
              
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></span> 

                <input type="email" class="form-control input-lg" name="nuevaCorreo" placeholder="Ingresar Correo"  required>

              </div>
<br>   
                <div class="input-group">
              
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i></span> 

                <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="nuevaTelefono" placeholder="Ingresar Teléfono" required>

              </div>
<br>
            </div>
  
          </div>

        </div>
```

**Php en el HTML de el boton eliminar categoria**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Publicá el código PHP y decinos que versión tenés en tu localhost y cual en el server.

Comment: agregue como respuesta los datos solicitados!!!

Comment: Ignacio, por favor editá tu pregunta original y agregá ahí lo que publicaste como _respuesta_. Después borra esa respuesta.

Comment: En tu controlador llamás a  `ModeloCategorias::mdlBorrarCategoria()`, pero en el modelo el método se llama `mdlEliminarCliente()`, tenés algo mal ahí?

Comment: Gracias por responder, como comenté arriba, el método era editar categorías y yo lo adapte a cliente, pero dejé los nombres de categoría, como botones, funciones etc, solo cambie en la base de datos.

Comment: Entiendo que estás reutilizando parte del código, pero desde PHP estás llamando a `ModeloCategorias::mdlBorrarCategoria()` y tendrías que llamar a `ModeloCategorias::mdlEliminarCliente()`. Ahí tenés un error o falta información en tu pregunta.

Comment: Ingreso el ModeloCategorias::mdlBorrarCategoria() por que el boton es de categorias, en ningun momento le puse "cliente" a ninguna funcion, tiene todo de categoria lo unico datos en la BD para captrarlos mediante input y guardarlos, como muestea la foto de arriba todo dice clientes, pero el codigo es de usuario, osea toda la interfaz cliente, el codigo sigue siendo categoria.

Comment: aclaro que nunca se a utilizado las funciones de : CLiente, Venta, reportes, de hecho los saque de la interfaz grafica.

Comment: Recordar que al utilizar la funcion de elimar categoria en mi localhost funciona bien, en cambio al subirlo a mi servidor web, deja de funcionar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comentarles que encontré el error, al invocar el método de eliminar, estaba mal escrito, ya que contenía una "C" mayúscula y era con minúscula, típico error de programación, me despido gracias por su tiempo!!!